# How to justify pursuing a Masters after a Ph.D. for Visa purposes?

Tags: phd, masters, germany, second-degree, biotechnology

I have recently completed my Ph.D. in Molecular Biology. Regarding my background, I have a BSc and an M.Sc. in biotechnology. During my Ph.D., I wanted to work extensively in the Neuroscience domain but since my project was already decided and was funded accordingly, I had no liberty to alter with what I wanted to do with it and had to complete it as per the expected methodology. This in no way means that I am not proficient in Molecular Biology. Nevertheless, I did another project (not so extensive) in the field of Neuroscience in order to satisfy my interest but the scope of the project was fairly basic and I did it on my own expenses.

Soon after completing my Ph.D., I applied for an MSc Neuroscience course in Germany and I recently got into it. I am really excited and happy about this opportunity to learn and work in fields of Clinical Neuroscience and Psychiatric Neurosciences and to finally get a proper specialization (that I am motivated for) for my CV.

Regarding the visa, I need to justify why I want to pursue a Master's after a PhD and I really can not think of how to make them happy about it? The university was quite happy to know about my motivation and everyone in the interview was supportive of my motive as well.

I would appreciate any inputs towards the required justification!

Comment: I don't know how the visa process works, but do you have any reason to believe that explaining the same way you did to the university / here would not work?

Comment: In the United States, it is common for universities to have an "International Student Services" office, or something similar. I imagine they would be best positioned to answer your question, so I would recommend seeing if this university has something similar. If you can't find it on your own, you might ask the graduate director.